# GetShortPathNameW returns the file extension. I want it to ignore the .exe

Tags: c++

I have GetShortPathNameW in C++ with MSVC 2008 Free Edition. I just want to use it so that it can search or return the filename without  the .exe extension. Any chance that someone could help me with that? The code is below that I have:

```
WCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH];
    LPCWSTR dataFilePath = wArgv[datafile_argv];

        // Hack for Windows in case there are unicode chars in the path.
    // The normal argv[] array has ????? instead of the unicode chars
    // and fails, so instead we manually get the short file name, which
    // is always using ANSI chars.
    if (wcschr(dataFilePath, '\\') == NULL)
    {
        GetCurrentDirectoryW(MAX_PATH, buffer);
        wcscat(buffer, L"\\");
        wcscat(buffer, dataFilePath);
        dataFilePath = &buffer[0];

    }

    if (GetShortPathNameW(dataFilePath, directoryPathBuffer, MAX_PATH) == 0)
    {
        platform->DisplayAlert("Unable to determine startup path: GetShortPathNameW failed.");
        game_file_name = NULL;
        return;
    }
```

Comment: you risk a buffer overrun. why not use c++ stuff such as `std::wstring`. oh, and to get the startup path (as opposed to current directory) use `GetModuleFilename` (if i recall the name correctly, check it). and better throw an exception to let caller deal with failure, rather than imposing a modal dialog

Comment: Is the question really just "How do I strip off the last 4 characters of a string?"

Comment: Yes @ David. Thats all I want.

Comment: Well, not of the string, but rather what GetShortPathNameW has. std::wstring for some reason does not work in this case for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

> I just want to use it so that it can search or return the filename without the .exe extension.

Sure, just use the [`PathRemoveExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773746.aspx) function. You just pass it a buffer of length `MAX_PATH` containing the string, and it strips off the extension (if one is present) in-place.

```
std::wstring path(MAX_PATH, L'\0');
if (!GetCurrentDirectoryW(MAX_PATH, &path[0]))
{
    throw std::runtime_error("The GetCurrentDirectory function failed");
}
PathRemoveExtension(&path[0]);
```

And I would recommend using either [`PathCombine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773571.aspx) or [`PathAppend`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773565.aspx) to concatenate path elements, rather than the C-style string manipulation functions. These functions are designed to work with paths, and automatically add the backslash (or whatever other path separator character) for you.

But I don't really understand the code you've posted in the question, starting with the comment:

```
// Hack for Windows in case there are unicode chars in the path.
// The normal argv[] array has ????? instead of the unicode chars
// and fails, so instead we manually get the short file name, which
// is always using ANSI chars.
```

Perhaps a simpler way of explaining this would be that the standard `argv[]` array, passed as a parameter to the entry point of a C program, is required to be an array of type `char`. On Windows, that means that it does not support Unicode characters. Support for Unicode requires you to use `wchar_t` (or one of the equivalent macros).

You can work around this problem in Windows specifically by using `wmain` as the entry point, instead of `main`. To this function, `argv[]` is an array of wide characters (`wchar_t`). I assume that you're cross-compiling the code for multiple operating systems, in which case you'll need to use some preprocessor magic to ensure that you get the right entry point when targeting Windows.

If you absolutely can't do that, then just call the [`GetCommandLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156.aspx) and [`CommandLineToArgv`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391.aspx) functions to retrieve the command line arguments, and then convert them into an `argv[]` style array that contains wide characters.

As an alternative to this, you could do as Alf suggested and call the [`GetModuleFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197.aspx) function, passing `NULL` as the first argument, to retrieve the path of your executable file.

Either way you approach it, it is important to realize that converting a short path is a *really* ugly hack and one that is actually subject to breaking if the underlying file system has short names disabled. Since your code is using Unicode APIs everywhere, there should be no problem for you to deal with Unicode characters in the path, as long as you obtain a valid path string in the first place.

Comment: +1 I want to set up some sock puppet accounts so that I can up vote more than once!